# Не могу добавить мультипроцессинг в свой скрипт

Tags: python-3.x, windows

Вот мой код

```
import requests
from multiprocessing import Pool


url = 'http://google.com'
path = 'proxy.txt'
handler_list = []

def get_file_list(path_to_file):
    global handler_list
    handler = open(path)
    handler_list = list(handler)
    handler.close()



def check_proxy(proxy_list):
    for x in proxy_list:
        try:
            proxy_url = x.split('\n',1)[0]
            print(proxy_url)
            requests.get(url,proxies={'http':'http://'+ proxy_url},timeout=(3.05,27))
            handle = open('good.txt','a')
            handle.write(proxy_url)
        except:
            continue


if __name__ == '__main__':
    get_file_list(path)
    #check_proxy(handler_list)
    pool = Pool()
    pool.map(check_proxy, handler_list)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

Если убрать мультипроцессинг и передать в `check_proxy()` `handler_list`, то все работает корректно, но если добавить мультипроцессинг то он передает по одному символу из `handler_list` и все, мне надо чтобы запросы `requests.get()` шли с мультипроцессингом.

Answer (score 0):

Вроде все верно сделал, но почему передает по символу непонятно.
Тогда попробуй сделать так:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    get_file_list(path)
    procs = []

    for handler in handler_list:
        proc = Process(target=check_proxy, args=(handler,))
        procs.append(proc)
        proc.start()

    for proc in procs:
        proc.join()
```

Это тоже самое. Но если результат снова будет тот самый, то больше всего ошибка здесь:

```
def get_file_list(path_to_file):
    global handler_list
    handler = open(path) # Если open возвращает строку, то ошибка в list(handler), поскольку list разбивает ее посимвольно.
    handler_list = list(handler)
    handler.close()
```